# How to load only part of a document in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and I have an html page that loads the source code from this page into a given div and I am using the code provided by the user rob-w which works fine but my main goal is to learn how to show only part of the returned text starting at a given value and ending at a given value after that

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    if (request.action == "getSource") {
      message.innerText = request.source;
    }
  });

  function onWindowLoad() {

    var message = document.querySelector("#message");


    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
      file: "getPagesSource.js"
    }, function() {
      // If you try and inject into an extensions page or the webstore/NTP you'll get an error
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        message.innerText = 'There was an error injecting script : \n' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message;
      }
    });
  }

  window.onload = onWindowLoad;
```

getPagesSource.js

```
// @author Rob W <http://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w>
// Demo: var serialized_html = DOMtoString(document);

function DOMtoString(document_root) {
    var html = '',
        node = document_root.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        switch (node.nodeType) {
        case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            html += node.outerHTML;
            break;
        case Node.TEXT_NODE:
            html += node.nodeValue;
            break;
        case Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
            html += '<![CDATA[' + node.nodeValue + ']]>';
            break;
        case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
            html += '<!--' + node.nodeValue + '-->';
            break;
        case Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
            // (X)HTML documents are identified by public identifiers
            html += "<!DOCTYPE " + node.name + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '') + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '') + '>\n';
            break;
        }
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
    return html;
}

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "getSource",
    source: DOMtoString(document)
});
```

I have played around with many DOM functions and getBy functions but I have not been able to apply them correctly and I don't think they are exactly what I am after. If someone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

My solution uses [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get an array containing all values between strings x and y but not including strings x and y.

```
function getStringsBetweenXandY(html) {
    var matches = html.match(/x[\s\S]*?y/g), i = matches.length;
    while(i--) {
        matches[i] = matches[i].match(/x([\s\S]*?)y/)[1];
    }
    return matches;
}

var array = getStringsBetweenXandY(html);
```

You need to make sure that strings x and y contain backslashes where necessary.

matches will contain an array or an array-like object containing all of the html fragments you are looking for

Comment: I tried adding var matches = html.match(/x.*?y/s); above return html; in getPagesSource.js and then instead of returning html I return matches but it doesnt return anything. Did I use it wrong or does X and Y have to be unique or does it find the first example of x and the first example of y after x?

Comment: It finds the first x and then the first y after x. If you want the last y after x, you can omit the question mark. Don't return matches. Return matches[0]. matches is an array.

Comment: I found by removing the /s and leaving it as / I am now getting the search results I wanted and all that's left to work out is now how to remove the searched values from the result

Comment: That's great to hear. See my revised answer for the solution without the searched values.

Comment: when I use return matches[0] i get the same as before and when I use [1] I get back undefined, 
also I found I am having problems including certain character combinations in the match for example:
var search = html.match(/"httpUrl":.*?},/); returns a value that exists
var search = html.match(/"httpUrl": ".*?},/); returns nothing and both examples are present in the code

Comment: Certain characters have special meanings in regular expressions. Let's start with parenthesis. matches[1] will be the first pattern in parenthesis, matches[2] the second, Etc. So you want to match on (.*?) not .*? (Special characters need to be escaped with backslahes if you are trying to match on them.) There are lots of detailed tutorials about regular expressions online. If you still need help please post the file you are trying to extract text from and which values you want to match on.

Comment: I will look up matching regular expressions and see how I go, one more thing would be this matches the first example of x and then y but how can you return the 2nd or 3rd example? is it possible?

Comment: For the second y html.match(/x(.*?y.*?)y/) For the third y html.match(/x(.*?y.*?y.*?)y/) But be careful. .* doesn't match newline characters without /s at the end.

Comment: I am struggling to get matching the second instance of x or y, I have looked into regular expressions and I now understand you are using non-greedy expressions but I still dont quite understand how to get it working

say you have a string "abbbbcccxvybbbxnnym" how would you apply what you said to return the string with the characters xnny which is the second instance of x and y?

Comment: You could use the global modifier like this html.match(/x.*?y/g) But javascript doesn't return parentheses expressions with the global modifier so that might not be what you want. Another option is to use lookbehind and lookahead like this html.match(/(?<=x).*?(?=y)/g); but lookbehind is not widely supported. I just tested it in Firefox and it isn't working, but it works in Chrome. The global modifier /g gives you all matches. Use /gi or /i for case insensitive searches. Your best bet is to use the first method with a second match on the result to remove the x and y so that it works in Firefox